# able to get the access token through Node but not in Karate DSL

Tags: api, karate

I am able to get the access token through request module in Node but similar approach in Karate DSL fails

```
Example:
Feature: Test token
Scenario: Fetch access token
Given url 'mysite/oauth/token'
And form field client_id  = 'xys'
And form field client_secret  = 'fddf'
And form field grant_type = 'client_credentials'
When method post
Then status 200
```

Regards,
Asif

Comment: And what does fails mean? What's the error?

Answer (score 0):

The `url` has to start with `http://` or `https://`. Please read the docs carefully.

Also refer to this demo example: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/oauth/oauth2.feature